# WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid

Tags: powershell

When I try to fetch the service information on remote computer I got an WINRM error.

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> invoke-command -computername Node1 -ScriptBlock {gsv}
 [Node1] Connecting to remote server Node1 failed with the following error      
 message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer 
 name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall 
 exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By 
 default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers
 within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (Node1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Did you enable windows remoting on the destination computer (`Enable-PSRemoting` or `winrm quickconfig`)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try below workaround to fix WINRM issue.

Connect to Remote server and run below command from cmd as a administrator.

```
    C:\Windows\system32>WinRM quickconfig
 WinRM service is already running on this machine.
 WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
 The following changes must be made:

 Create a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this
 machine.

 Make these changes [y/n]? y

 WinRM has been updated for remote management.

 Created a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this
 machine.
```

Comment: I am downloading auditlogs from office 365 with Powershell and Search-UnifiedAuditLog cmdlet. Seems to work fine but after hours running the proccess correctly, I get the same error. Do you have any clue of what could be going wrong? Why it didn't fail at the start?

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked the remote computer's firewall rules? The default rule only allows IPs in the local subnet.

To allow other IPs:

1. Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
2. Click *Inbound Rules*
3. Double-click *Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)* for the *Public* profile
4. Click the *Scope* tab
5. Under *Remote IP address*, add any IPs you need

[image: A screenshot of a WinRM firewall rule on which the remote IP address must be in the local subnet]

Comment: On Server Core you can run `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" dir=in action=allow service=any enable=yes profile=any localport=5985 protocol=tcp`

Answer (score 7):

Is WinRM enabled on both computers???

Run

```
winrm quickconfig
```

and check it.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the Windows Remote Management Service as mentioned by user @smwk in comments section.

Start > Search > Services > Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) restart the service.

[image: Restart the WRM service]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with port 5985?

Try to Telent port with IP address

1. Open CMD run as administrator
2. Telent 10.xx.xx.xxx 5985

Comment: And if you can't telnet to port 5985 what does that tell you, what's the next step?

Comment: Restarting the Windows Remote Management service worked for me.

Comment: Well, windows typically doesn't have telnet and winrm is a windows thing we are checking so most machines will typically fail to telnet ... so if you get an error that telnet is not recognized command it just means you don't have the utility - windows machines typically do not have it. So, this is not a great troubleshooting step for the everyday user. For me restarting the service did work thanks SMWK

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue... with exactly the same error message.

It turned out, that the Hyper-V server was simply not connected to network!

Therefore, before engaging in complex troubleshooting, just ensure the right network cable is connected to the right network adapter...